# JS onclick / onmouseover передать аргуменот функции

Tags: javascript

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('docs_item_name') != []){
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('docs_item_name');
    for(i = 0; i<=a.length - 1; i++){
        var filename = a[i].innerHTML;
                a[i].onmouseover = function(){
                    console.log(filename);  
                };
        }
    }
```

При наведении на ссылку, в консоле выводится последний элемент в массиве.
Как передать текущей filename  и повешить событие?

Comment: Покажите ваш HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно как-нибудь [так (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7WYsC/).

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('docs_item_name') != []){
     var a = document.getElementsByClassName('docs_item_name');
     for(i = 0; i<=a.length - 1; i++){
         var filename = a[i].innerHTML;
             a[i].onmouseover = (function( opt ){
                 return function(){
                     console.log( opt );
                 };
             })( filename );
     }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!    п